# How would I make grouped lists through querying using MongoDB aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, set, grouping, aggregation

Say that I have an attribute with something like letter grades of a student, using a structure like:

```
Students
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": string
    },
    "student_id": int,
    "grades": string,
    "student_name": string,
...
}
```

and I want to go through the database and group the students by storing them in sets based on each letter grade (assuming that each student has a unique name) like:
A+ : [Chris, Ada, Lee], A- : [John, Lisa], …
How would I structure the query through using something like $addToSet (hopefully without having to manually type each letter grade)?

I've tried $group-ing the students with grades and using $match to try and iterate through the list of grades, but I haven't come across any errorless ways of creating sets without just getting an integer count  of how many students have that grade (ex. 7 students have grade of A+. But who are the students?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to do, here's one way to `"$group"` by `"grades"` and get an array of all `"student_name"` with that grade.

```js
db.Students.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$grades",
      "names": {"$push": "$student_name"},
      "count": {"$count": {}}
    }
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4N1zfwR2qTO).

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you!
a short side note: $count may not work as an aggregation operator at times; during those cases, $sum can be used as an accumulator.